# Raise an exception if a specific key exists in a dictionary, but return successfully if it does not exist

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

Suppose I have the following function:

```
def test():
  ...
  if x['error']:
    raise
```

This would raise an exception regardless if `x['error']` is defined or not.

Instead if I try this, it doesn't throw any exception:

```
def test():
  ...
  try:
    if x['error']:
      raise
  except:
    return
```

How can I test for a specific value and return an exception if it is defined, and to return successfully if it is not defined?

Comment: FYI, the keyword `raise` by itself is invalid outside an active exception handler.

Comment: @Keith what would you suggest in this case? Would `raise Exception()` be a good alternative?

Comment: Define a new exception as subclass of Exception, and raise that. `raise MyError(x['error'])`, after determining that the value exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def test():
  ...
  if x.get('error'):
    raise
```

You can avoid unintentionally raising an error using the dictionary's built in `get` function. Get will return `None` if the value at the specified key does not exist instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to return error as string:

```
>>> def test():
    try:
        if x['error']:raise
    except Exception as err:
        return err

>>> test()
NameError("name 'x' is not defined",)
```

If you want to an error to occur:

```
>>> def test():
    try:
        if x['error']:raise
    except:
        raise

>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    test()
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 3, in test
    if x['error']:raise
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
def check_not_exist(d,k):
   #if keys exists in dict,raise it
   if k in d:
     raise
   else:
     return True
```